# How to read byte array from serial port in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, arrays

I have a problem with C# serial port programming
my aim send ByteArray to serial port and than get as ByteArray.
but I can not get from serial port. I tried:

```
string gelen = port.ReadExisting();
   int asd = port.ReadByte();
   string qwe = port.ReadLine();
```

Could any one tell me what’s wrong?
 Thanks

my code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO.Ports;

    namespace serial_port_app
    {

        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {

            public Form1()
            {       
                InitializeComponent();

            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                int text1, text2,text3,text4,text5, text6;

                Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out text1);
                byte byteValue1 = Convert.ToByte(text1);

                Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out text2);
                byte byteValue2 = Convert.ToByte(text2);

                Int32.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out text3);
                byte byteValue3 = Convert.ToByte(text3);

                Int32.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out text4);
                byte byteValue4 = Convert.ToByte(text4);

                Int32.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out text5);
                byte byteValue5 = Convert.ToByte(text5);

                Int32.TryParse(textBox6.Text, out text6);
                byte byteValue6 = Convert.ToByte(text6);


                byte[] byteArray = new byte[6];

                byteArray[0]=byteValue1;
                byteArray[1]=byteValue2;
                byteArray[2]=byteValue3;
                byteArray[3]=byteValue4;
                byteArray[4]=byteValue5;
                byteArray[5]=byteValue6;


                SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8,      StopBits.One);

                port.Open();
                port.Write(byteArray,0,6);

>>>>>>>>>>>>>   string text = port.ReadExisting();
>>>>>>>>>>>>>   int asd = port.ReadByte();
>>>>>>>>>>>>>   string qwe = port.ReadLine();

                int n=dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = text;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = asd;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = qwe;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = text4;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = text5;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = text6;



                    if ((n % 2) == 0)
                        dataGridView1.Rows[n].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                    else
                        dataGridView1.Rows[n].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;

                    port.Close();
            }
```

***EDIT for correct answer:***

**delete:**

```
string text = port.ReadExisting();
int asd = port.ReadByte();
string qwe = port.ReadLine();
```

**and add:**

```
port.DtrEnable = true;
 port.RtsEnable = true;

 int bytes = port.BytesToRead;
 byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
 port.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
```

Comment: What happened when you tried those things that you tried?

Comment: You are ignoring the need to take care of the handshake signals.  Set the DtrEnabled and RtsEnabled properties to *true*.  Use another program like Hyperterminal or Putty to get confidence in the electrical connection and driver.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, program worked, your answer correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a `Byte` array rather than a `String` use [`BytesToRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.bytestoread(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: unfortunately, did not work.

Comment: I added  is that DtrEnabled and RtsEnabled properties to true to my program and worked. thanks for answer.

Comment: @hamdi Great. You don't need to edit the title to "solved". You need to click the grey tick to mark an answer as accepted. If Hans had an answer I'd say accept his, but in his absence I'll take the tick!

Comment: @HamdiBayhan looks like this worked for you, can you accept it?